# How do you stop a Java RMI application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I followed some tutorials (i.e [this one](https://raphiinconcordia.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/rmi-tutorial.pdf))on Java RMI in Eclipse and got the program running.

The trouble is, I can't find any instructions on how to stop the RMI program from running. I want to know for general knowledge purposes, but also because when I try running the program again (after making changes) I get a message that the port is already bound to the previous run which is still active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button on the right can be used to toggle between active output consoles. When you reach the console for the RMI server you want to end, click the red square (on the left)

[image: Eclipse end console process]